# Lagrange Multipliers with a Whole Number Constraint

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

How do I formulate a Lagrange Multipliers' constraint to be a whole number? How can I solve a problem like
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{max: } &F(x,y) = C\\ \mathrm{s.t.:} &y\in\mathbb{Z}
\end{align}$$

Comment: After you choose $a$ and $m$, $f(x)$ is still a function that you can maximize. What do you mean by "maximize" here?

Comment: The last formatting might have been a bit unclear. I have edited the post, so that only my question is stated as is.

Comment: "$y$ is an integer" is the same as $\sin\pi y=0$ (but I don't think that will work for Lagrange multipliers).